# two-stage rotation animation alert in console UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, rotation, warnings, uiimagepickercontroller

In my UIViewController class, I created an UIImagePickerController like this :

```
-(BOOL)startCameraPickerFromViewController{

if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])       
    return NO;
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;    

picker.allowsEditing = NO ;
picker.delegate = appDelegate.uiImagePickerDelegate;

// Picker is displayed asynchronously.


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
return YES; 
}
```

When I call my function, I get :

> Using two-stage rotation animation. To
>   use the smoother single-stage
>   animation, this application must
>   remove two-stage method
>   implementations.

I read in the UIViewController Class Reference on Apple site that I attempt to use the old way to use rotation. But in my UIViewController, I've never write :

```
– willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

or

```
– willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

methods.

I've tryed to override the

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

but it's the same problem.

I think that the problem come from UIImagePickerController. Is there a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "Using two-stage rotation animation" warning with UIImagePickerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878947/getting-using-two-stage-rotation-animation-warning-with-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are pushing the UIImagePickerController within another UIViewController. See this SO answer: [Getting "Using two-stage rotation animation" warning with UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878947/getting-using-two-stage-rotation-animation-warning-with-uiimagepickercontroller)