# UIImagePickerController seems to be "broken" in 4.0. Anyone else?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Been working on a 3.1.3 application and recently upgraded to the 4.0 SDK. I'm still building with a Base SDK of 3.1.3 and testing on a 3.1.3 device as well as a device running 4. On 4.0 device, when a UIImagePickerController is displayed I get the following messages:

```
Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.

Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported when rotating more than one view controller or view controllers not the window delegate
```

When the application runs on the 3.1.3 device, it works just fine. No logs, the image shows up when I pick it. When it runs (same code) on the 4.0 device, the logs appear and the delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Does not return the image as one of the dictionary keys of `info`. So it appears to be broken or I am using a deprecated method or something. Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with iOS 4.0. You'll have to wait and hope it's fixed with 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're alone on this issue:

[Getting "Using two-stage rotation animation" warning with UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878947/getting-using-two-stage-rotation-animation-warning-with-uiimagepickercontroller)

Unfortunately, no one has posted an accepted answer yet.  Best of luck!