# Memory leak while opening UIPickerController and closing it

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev.

I've following code.

```
- (void) onUploadButtonClick
{
    UIImagePickerController* imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:imgPicker];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    [imgPicker release];
}
```

I'm running the app and profiling for memory leaks, so by just clicking on the button and closing it, without doing anything I am getting memory leak. I'm running this on simulator.

Any ideas why this happens ?

UPDATE : Leak info from profiler's console
Leaked Object,# Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame

```
Malloc 32.50 KB,3   < multiple >    99840   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear
 Malloc 32.50 KB,   0xa083800   33280   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear
 Malloc 32.50 KB,   0x7840a00   33280   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear
 Malloc 32.50 KB,   0x7806a00   33280   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear


Leaked Object,# Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 32.50 KB,    0xa083800   33280   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear


Leaked Object,# Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 32.50 KB,    0x7840a00   33280   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear


Leaked Object,# Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 32.50 KB,    0x7806a00   33280   MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear


Leaked Object,# Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 128.00 KB,   0x128de000  131072  MusicLibrary    ReadITImageDB
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever do something like that with a UIImagePickerController? You're literally killing your actual rootViewController.

```
 [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:imgPicker];
```

Just remove this line and everything will work fine.

Comment: Actually even by removing that line memory is still leaked. 

That line is to avoid following message in console, any other way to remove that message ?

2011-11-05 16:25:21.791 PostCardPrinter[4769:207] Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.
2011-11-05 16:25:21.793 PostCardPrinter[4769:207] Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported when rotating more than one view controller or view controllers not the window delegate

Comment: Found this link. Hope it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878947/getting-using-two-stage-rotation-animation-warning-with-uiimagepickercontrolle

Comment: Yes, that is how I did and posted in original post. Still getting the leak

Comment: What object exactly is getting leaked? In the Leaks instrument, select Leaks, then swap leaked blocks to Call Tree and check two boxes in the left - invert call tree and hide system libraries. That will show you when exactly the leak occurs and which line gives you the leak.

Comment: Total % # Leaks Bytes  Symbol Name
100 2  160.50 KB      -[MyiewController onUploadButtonClick]
This is what I'm getting ... still no any clue ... :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `UINavigationController` and push the `UIImagePickerController` onto it, or present the `UIImagePickerController` modally. By setting the `UIImagePickerController` as your root controller you are loosing the previous `rootViewController` and will not be able to return to it. The memory leak could be due to the fact that that the root `UIViewController` has incorrectly implemented `viewDidUnload` and dealloc methods.