# Error: Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios-simulator

I am working on bar code scan application. 
I got *sample source code*.
While scanning the image, i am taking image from photo gallery where i have saved some bar code images.

But does not scanning and showing in console as
**2012-06-04 14:09:00.136 Reader Sample[467:207] Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported when rotating more than one view controller or view controllers not the window delegate**

What this error log is all about, can anybody please help me.

**Any help is appreciated**

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2878947/474535 it may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what should i do

Given the console message, I'd say that you shouldn't use two stage rotation. That is, instead of using the methods `-[will/did]AnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` and `-[will/did]AnimateSecondHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`, use the newer one-step rotation methods `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.