# How to remove from this Debugger warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting “Using two-stage rotation animation” warning with UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878947/getting-using-two-stage-rotation-animation-warning-with-uiimagepickercontrolle)

In my iphone app i have a login screen after loging in i am navigating to a class ( i have tab barcontroller with 5 tabs here)

like this i am programmatically creating the tabbar

```
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *arrControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    //Add PunchClock to tab View Controller
    PunchClock* objPunchClock = [[PunchClock alloc] initWithTabBar];
    NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objPunchClock];
    NavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [arrControllers addObject:NavigationController];
    [NavigationController release];
    [objPunchClock release];
 tabBarController .viewControllers = arrControllers;

    [arrControllers release];
    [self.view addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

after logging in while navigating to this class i am getting this Debugger warning

```
2012-07-07 12:09:27.988 WorkForce[1475:207] Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.
2012-07-07 12:09:28.074 WorkForce[1475:207] Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported when rotating more than one view controller or view controllers not the window delegate
```

what is it mean,,,how to remove this warning?  please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what that error message means but when you get such a specific error message, it is often helpful to do a search with [the entire error message in quotes](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22To%20use%20the%20smoother%20single-stage%20animation%22) to see if anyone else has encountered it.

Apparently they have. Please report back and tell us what it means.

Comment: if i ignore those debugger warnings,ill it be a problem for my app?

Answer (score 0):

The two-halves animation methods like `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` are an older approach.  If you've implemented these methods, they should be removed so that the one-step scheme (in this case, `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`) can be used.

Comment: no i am not using any animation codes like those