# UIImagePickerController console message

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController for selecting images from the photo library. But I am getting a message on the console saying `"Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations."`

What is this due to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several people appear to be having the same problem. None of these links provide a solution (as far as I can tell), so this post is intended just as a starting point for more searching. I have made it CW.

- [stackoverflow: Single-Stage vs Two-Stage Animation for iPhone Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048781)
- [cocoabuilder: how to change to the smoother single stage animation](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284643-how-to-change-to-the-smoother-single-stage-animation.html)
- [stackoverflow: tabbarcontroller and navigationcontrollers in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756536/tabbarcontroller-and-navigationcontrollers-in-landscape-mode-episode-ii)
- [Apple support: 11186784](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11186784)

Answer (score 0):

That normally means you have implemented one of:

```
willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

on one of your view controllers, even if they are empty. This is neither wrong nor deprecated, the message just say it could possibly done better if you moved your implementation to: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`